# Script tag runs twice in universal react application (FB Plugin)

Tags: facebook, reactjs

I'm trying to include my facebook page plugin in my react app. I'm trying to achieve this using [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet) but I've run into an issue. If I put this in as a script tag as suggested by the docs, the script get's run twice yet only added to the `<head>` section once... I'm using a [starter kit](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example).

Here is what I've got

Html.jsx (responsible for rendering out the whole html page, [link to file](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/blob/master/src/helpers/Html.js)):

```
render() {
const {assets, component, store} = this.props
const content = component ? ReactDOM.renderToString(component) : ''
const head = Helmet.rewind()

return (
  <html lang="en-us">
    <head>
      ...
      {head.script.toComponent()}
      ...
)
```

In my App.jsx:

```
<Helmet
      script={[
        // {"type": 'text/javascript', "innerHTML": `{!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){}...cut down for brevity;console.log('I was fired');}`}
      ]}
      {...config.app.head}/>
```

Above log statement fires twice for some reason leading to an `Facebook Pixel Error: Duplicate Pixel ID: XYZ`

Let me know if more information is needed

Answer (score 3):

**Note that**, per the [source](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/blob/master/src/Helmet.js#L197), `react-helmet` blows away all server head tags it renders, then recreates them. I don't fully understand why they do this (perhaps they could only replace tags that have changed? maybe enumerating the attributes that have changed is somehow difficult?) but this is what is causing your problem.

I know because I have the same problem ;)

As for a **solution**, here are some possibilities:

- stop using react-helmet to manage tracking pixels/scripts/snippets - instead just paste them into your equivalent of `renderPage()` and/or `index.html`
- create a pull request for react-helmet that stops doing this (or just ask them, that might be faster!)
- wrap said code in some kind of guard (put an attribute on the `window` object, then only run any of that stuff if the attribute is not found)
- create a pull request for react-helmet that allows you to say 'no-re-render' on a certain element or something along those lines

I haven't found a solution that I really like, but any of these should work, good luck :)

Note that I have created an [issue here](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/149)

Answer (score 1):

As a side-note, if you include your scripts in the `body`, it will render twice. Hence, I added them in the `head` using `defer` to keep acceptable performances.